# IE 11 the cursor doesn't change immediately when selecting from empty space to text

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer, mouseevent, internet-explorer-11

I am using IE 11, I noticed that the cursor doesn't change immediately from pointer to designed cursor when selecting from empty space to text. It's working correctly in Firefox. Any idea?

For example, I have text here:

```
    .text {cursor: text;}
    <span class="text">This is the sample text.</span>
```

When I put my mouse down on right empty space after the sample sentence, and drag from right to left to select text, I expect the mouse cursor will be change immediately to "text" cursor when the mouse reaches the period, but the cursor doesn't change immediately in IE 11, sometimes the cursor starts to change when the mouse reaches "text" or even "sample".

Comment: Any code so we can test what you mean?

Comment: @Shilly please see my updated question, thx

Answer (score 1):

For me on IE11, if I start dragging outside of the textbox, the pointer only changes once I release the mouse button. In chrome and firefox, it changes the moment you hover the text.

I think this might be default IE11 behaviour, since I can't really find any related info easily.

What did work for me, is adding text:hover with the same styling. Then the cursor immediately changes once you hover a character, even while dragging.

```css
.text,
.text:hover {
  cursor: text;
}
```

```html
<span class="text">This is the sample text.</span>
```

Comment: Thanks Shilly. The reason why I was asking the question is because I noticed if the pointer doesn't change immediately in IE when dragging from outside of the textbox, it will miss my own mouseover and mouseout function, those two functions only get called when the cursor get changed. So, adding hover is not that helpful, we may need another workaround.

Comment: What work do those hover functions do that is important while selecting the text?